# can i add a common helper text for two textfields imported from MUI in reactjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, uitextfield

this is my code for password container

```css
.password-form-container {
  width: 85%;
  height: 7%;
  position: relative;
  top: 230px;
  left: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div className="password-form-container">
  <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Password" variant="outlined" size="small" className="name-container" helperText='Use 8 or more characters with a mix of letters, numbers & symbols' />
  <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Confirm" variant="outlined" size="small" className="name-container" />
</div>
```

[this page is my target but iam not getting[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YpE5.png)
[Please look into this image this is the page iam working on but since the helper text is belong to the first text field it is restricted to that but i want that helper text to be like that in the first picture please look into that picture also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3oAX.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can add CSS like that image. The class of `HelperText` is `.MuiFormHelperText-root`

```
.MuiFormHelperText-root {
  width: 50%; //or what you want
}
```

And second `Textfield` can be empty

Comment: where should i put this css

Comment: @KalimuthuK where you write ```.password-form-container ``` style, you can put ```.MuiFormHelperText-root``` or any CSS file or write as internal style

Comment: it is not working still please help me